# How do I configure the new recurring contribution feature in Webform CiviCRM module?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

The current -dev version of webform_civicrm module includes a first pass at adding recurring contribution functionality. This seems like a good place to post some examples of how it can be used.

Following existing logic in webform_civicrm creation of the recurring series uses the CiviCRM APIs. There is no additional code specific to Contributions, Events, or Membership.

Below please find:
**Example 1:** Give user option to pay for Event Registration either right now - or in monthly installments

Comment: I'll add examples/screenshots shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Example 1: Give user option to pay for Event Registration either right now - or in monthly installments**

Scenario: Parent (Primary Contact) signs up Child for Swim Club. Give the Parent the option to pay all Fees right now - or in Installments.

**1a) set up the fields in the new Recurring Contribution section** in the CiviCRM tab. In order for webform_civicrm module to set up a Recurring Contribution two elements are required: Number of Installments and their Frequency.

[image]
**1b) configure the webform fields:** I've added a select / checkbox so the User can indicate if they wish to pay all now - or in 10 installments. There is a Conditional that if checked Yes -> shows the Number of Installments field; That field is disabled and hidden.

[image]
**1c) Event registration for Child:** Child is registered as a Participant we see the first Payment.

[image]
**1d) the Primary Contact's record contains the first Contribution in this Series**

[image]

**1e) the Primary Contact's record contains the Recurring Contribution Series** - details.

[image]
**Note** 
even though the monthly contributions will process as specified, subsequent installments don't (yet) get associated with/credited to the Event registration. CiviCRM Core can't (yet) associate a Recurring series with an Event registration.

Comment: Does this work with Paypal? Seems like you are using iATS?

Comment: This will work with any payment processor that webform civicrm works with; I have one client who used PayPal Pro eg

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind me picking your brain for a second. Is there any way to get this to work for standard recurring payments, exactly as they are on a Civicontribute form for memberships? Instead of installments, how about just using Webform CiviCRM to initiate a recurring payment in Civi/Paypal (for instance)

Comment: Have you tried Memberships -> multiple periods and then set recurring to once every year? It's not the classic Membership recurring as in CiviCRM native - but it actually has benefits e.g. it's producing a recurring series that you can Edit (if you want to up the $ amount at some point);

Comment: KarinG - I am also trying to get this to work. The payment page seems to show the 'Total Amount' being paid, but not the installment amount.

Comment: That's correct - it's saying here total X and would you like to pay in installments yes/no (I usually define them to monthly 10x or 12x). If the amount can not be divided equally it will even make a rounding adjustment (charges first installment and then splits up the balance equally over installment payments);

Comment: Thank you. I like that option (especially for events). In this thread: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/2557997 there is a patch that seems to read, if Installments = 1, then set it to be a recurring contribution. Have you used that, or think it's a good idea? We do like recurring annual contributions

Comment: No - not using a patch; just using what I added to webform_civicrm module (native); recurring annual: you could sign up for 3 terms -> then 3x Membership fee -> pay in 3 installments -> annually;

Comment: Thanks! I think I have everything I need now. This set of modules is great and lets us do so many cool things but it takes a different way of thinking.

Comment: "CiviCRM Core can't (yet) associate a Recurring series with an Event registration."  Does this mean that over time, the event registration will still show as money is owed, even after the user has made all of their payments?  Is this still an outstanding issue?  Thanks for the great and detailed writeup!

Comment: Yes that’s correct - the total Event Registration fees owed will add up to the total of the installment payments but there is no direct link - they don’t all automatically become  partial payments to (perhaps) multiple event registrations (example: sign two kids up for swim club and pay with one monthly payment for both over a period of 10mo). So account statements are the way to go. Simply listing obligation and payments of type Event fee in one View eg

Comment: Hi KarinG, thank you for confirming!  Does it still work this way if the webform only registers a person for one event?  One person registering for one event.  (I hear you about using account statements.  That would be a change for how we do things so just trying to suss out the possibilities.)