# Donations Page with recurring and one time

Tags: contribution-page

Is it possible to design a single donation page that offers both recurring and one time?  I'm trying to avoid two separate forms.

I have Webform for Civi setup as well as eWay.

If yes, any links would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the integration of this with Webforms (I assume you can do it), but if you can use a regular CiviCRM contribution page, you'll be able to set up a page that offers both recurring donations and one time donations.

Under Contributions>Manage Contribution Pages>"Your contribution page">Amounts tab

You will see a field to define fixed donation amounts:
[image: civicrm fixed donation amounts]

You will also see a field to define whether you'd like people to define their own donation amounts:
[image: civicrm user-defined donation amounts]

The third field you want to pay attention to is for defining recurring contributions as you'd like to. This will put a checkbox where a user can decide whether they want to make a recurring donation or a single donation:
[image]

Put it all together... and your CiviCRM contribution page will look something like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since recently - you can also do this in webform_civicrm! It works a little different in that a donor can select an amount -> and then the donor can specify whether to pay this:

1) in one go; or 
2) in installments - and of course the installment part is completely configurable a la webform components [whether you let the user select options or whether you set specific ones].

If the donor selects an amount that can't be divided by the #installments it will automatically round down the subsequent installments and charge a little more for the first one;

**Example:**
[How do I configure the new recurring contribution feature in Webform CiviCRM module?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/how-do-i-configure-the-new-recurring-contribution-feature-in-webform-civicrm-mod)

That's for an Event Registration - webform_civicrm does not care if you do Contributions or Event Registrations (or Memberships);