# Webform CiviCRM : Do recurring contributions now get allocated to the right event registration

Tags: webform-civicrm

I have been reading with interest about the new recurring contribution feature for event registrations via Webform CiviCRM (see [here](https://civicrm.org/blog/karing/webform-civicrm-integration-new-features-added-in-2018-and-looking-ahead-to-2019) and [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/how-do-i-configure-the-new-recurring-contribution-feature-in-webform-civicrm-mod)).  We have a large population of our users who need to do payment plans and this seems like a great option to support that.

My one concern comes from [this (older) thread](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/how-do-i-configure-the-new-recurring-contribution-feature-in-webform-civicrm-mod), where the author writes: "CiviCRM Core can't (yet) associate a Recurring series with an Event registration."

The way I interpret this is:

- the user registers for an event at (e.g.) $100.
- Their first payment is recorded as a contribution record against the event registration.
- Their subsequent payments are not recorded as contributions against the event registration.
- So their event registration will still show them owing money, even when the contribution series is fully paid.

Is that correct?  And more importantly -- is it still the case today?

Thank you